# Ionic 3 application not compiling

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created a Ionic application in Ionic3 and firebase and it works perfectly on my own PC but as soon as my friend runs it, it does not work. He gets the following error

> Runtime Error
>   Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [StatusBar, SplashScreen, [object Object], AuthProvider, AngularFireAuth, UserProvider, ImghandlerProvider, ?[object Object]?, ...]
>
> Stack
>   Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [StatusBar, SplashScreen, [object Object], AuthProvider, AngularFireAuth, UserProvider, ImghandlerProvider, ?[object Object]?, ...]

Here is the `app.module.ts` file in my project

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { ErrorHandler, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
    import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

    import { config } from './app.firebaseconfig';

    import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
    import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';

    import { MyApp } from './app.component';
    import { AuthProvider } from '../providers/auth/auth';
    import { UserProvider } from '../providers/user/user';
    import { ImghandlerProvider } from '../providers/imghandler/imghandler';
    import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
    import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser';
    import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path/ngx';
    import { RequestsProvider } from '../providers/requests/requests';
    import { ChatProvider } from '../providers/chat/chat';
    import { GroupsProvider } from '../providers/groups/groups';
    import { CommandProvider } from '../providers/command/command';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        MyApp
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {tabsPlacement: 'top'}),
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config)
      ],
      bootstrap: [IonicApp],
      entryComponents: [
        MyApp
      ],
      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
        AuthProvider,
        AngularFireAuth,
        UserProvider,
        ImghandlerProvider,
        FileChooser,
        File,
        FilePath,
        RequestsProvider,
        ChatProvider,
        GroupsProvider,
        CommandProvider
      ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Any idea of why this is happening? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your current system environment. I may be the latest version of ionic and node You need to downgrade your ionic and node versions for compatibility. Next remove the node_modules folder and also remove packg-lock.json file and run

```
npm i
```

after that run

```
 npm rebuild node-sass
```

after run, this successfully run

```
npm i firebase@current_verion_in_your_packg.json
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Please check your packages and imports. There is a mix of ionic 4 and ionic 3 native packages. If you are using ionic 3, you have some native packages meant for ionic 4, that is all packages that end with `ngx`, those are meant for ionic 4. So following are incorrect:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path/ngx';
```

Please remove and reinstall these by checking the ionic 3 documentation on how to install them, here for example documention on [`File`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file/)